# First order logic negation of a bracket

Tags: first-order-logic

I have this problem:

$\neg\left((\forall X)(\exists Y)p(X,Y)\right)$

How do I correctly propagate the negation into the bracket?

like this?

$\neg(\forall X)\neg(\exists Y)\neg p(X,Y)$

Or do I only negate $\forall X$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

I should think that would have been one of the first things you learned.  If it is NOT true that "for all x, p is true" then we can only say "for **some** x, p is not true".  And if it is NOT true that "there are some x such that p is true" we can say "for **all x** p is not true".

Answer (score 0):

You do so as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\lnot((\forall X)(\exists Y)p(X, Y))&\equiv \lnot (\forall X)(\exists Y)p(X, Y) \\
&\equiv (\exists X)\lnot(\exists Y)p(X, Y) \\
&\equiv (\exists X)(\forall Y)\lnot p(X, Y).
\end{align}$$